# Checkboxlist within gridview cell cannot count all selected items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have these checkboxlist each cell of a gridview. Now, I am trying to get the selected items each checkboxlist but it failed. Any help please! Thanks!

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvReg.Rows)
            {
                for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 4 - 1; ctr++)
                {
                    if (ctr == 0)
                    {
                        szCheckBoxListName = "cblMultiSelect";
                        szRegionName = "lblRegionName";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        szCheckBoxListName = "cblMultiSelect" + ctr;
                        szRegionName = "lblRegionName" + ctr;
                    }

                    cbl=(CheckBoxList)gvRow.Cells[ctr].FindControl(szCheckBoxListName);

                    if (cbl.Items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (ListItem li in cbl.Items)
                        {
                            if (li.Selected)
                            {
                                iItemCount = iItemCount + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

itemCount returns zero always even if I have selected several items on those checkboxlists.

Comment: have you debug your project? any exceptions? debug and check you get object for `cbl`

Comment: @Damith, yes, I get the object for cbl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you data binding on Page_Load method? If yes, you must do this:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = Your Datas;
}
```